# Is it possible to modify icons using an if statement?

Tags: javascript

So I was participating in a 5 day coding challenge which explained the very, very, very basics of HTML, CSS & JavaScript.

Where I was presented a new challenge on a daily basis. 
Now I already succeeded and finished the challenge with a 100% score.

But one of the challenges was to modify your icons when you're hovering over them with your cursor. With the modification being enlarging the icon when hovered over and reverting back to it's normal size when the cursor moves away from it.

I managed to do this with the basic easy method below.

```
<script>
    function ingredientsHover() {
        document.getElementById('ingredients').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
    }


    function ingredientsNormal() {
        document.getElementById('ingredients').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
        // document.write("Normal");  
    }


    function preparationHover() {
        document.getElementById('preparation').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
    }


    function preparationNormal() {
        document.getElementById('preparation').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
    }
</script>
```

Now what I'm wondering is, if you could get the same results by using a if statement and 1 function?

Or am I overthinking things or could this be done even easier?

Thanks for any input, I'm still learning a lot!

Comment: The answer, in short, is "yes, it can be done using an `if` statement". Though, can you include the relevant HTML?

Comment: Might be possible with CSS only

Comment: That's what I was thinking; this is possible using only CSS using a `hover` rule.

Comment: if your code works, and looking for optimizing it then this isn't the correct place for this type of questions, [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is better suited

Comment: But threads at codereview tend to just die alone...

Comment: Please post the code that calls these functions.

Comment: Oh wow! thanks for the replies! 

You want to see HTML tags corresponding to the script? 

<section id="ingredients" onmouseover="ingredientsHover()" onmouseout="ingredientsNormal()">

Same goes for preparation.

Comment: @marten.philip please [edit] your post, your comments won't last forever